# encrypted file is converted to buffer on IPFS

Tags: node.js, typescript, cryptojs, ipfs

I'm encrypting a a text file locally using the crypto module from node.js and upload the file to IPFS. I'm trying to then download the file and decrypt it. But once I upload the encrypted file to IPFS, it seems to change to a buffer.

It looks somewhat like this before upload (I only copied the first line):

```
N�&��6-d�9L% 9���E��k�ir�C��ڤ|%B5-(���i�
...
...
```

And it looks like this after download:

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[1,78,211,38,190,164,54,25,...])
```

I tried to convert it to multiple encodings, but that doesn't seem to solve anything. Is there a way to upload it in a different format (which stays the same on IPFS) or is there a way to convert the buffer back and decrypt it?

This is the code I use for encryption:

```
    export const encrypt = (buffer, key) => {
    const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr';

    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);

    const result = Buffer.concat([iv, cipher.update(buffer), cipher.final()]);
    return result;
};
```

Comment: Your encryption code seems to use buffers, so why would it be hard to decrypt using the same method? By the way, are you sure the result is not a buffer before upload? How did you get you string before upload? Is it possible you used a display method that automatically converts to string?

Comment: I don't know why, but decryption works with the first file (before upload) and not with the second. I save the encrypted file before I upload it (first snippet) and then once I donwloaded it (second snippet).

Comment: Can't you just call `result.toString('hex')` to get a hex string format?